# Javascript doesn't change CSS inside of a recursive function until the recursion ends

Tags: javascript

I a trying to create a page where the background cycles through every hex value (from #000000 to #FFFFFF). This is the JS function I am using:

```
function Colours(count)
        {   
            count +=1;
            if (count > 16777215)
            {
                count = 0;
            }                   
            hex = count.toString(16);
            while (hex.length < 6)
            {
                hex = "0" + hex;
            }
            hex = "#" + hex;
            document.body.style.background = hex;
            window.setTimeout(Colours(count),10);   
        }
```

It is called when a button is clicked and is given the argument -1 (so the first hex value is #000000).

After some diagnosis, it seems that it only changes the colour once the recursion ends (in this case I am presuming once it reaches its' stack limit at #006446). This function will process briefly before changing the background colour to the final hex code it reached. How can I get it to change the colour every time it enters the function rather than completing the stack at the end.

Comment: The DOM is not going to update in a while/for loop. Should be dupes on how to do it with setTimeout

Comment: Change `window.setTimeout(Colours(count),10); ` to `window.setTimeout(function(){Colours(count)},10); `

Comment: it is because `document.body.style.background = hex;` sets the background color and is called after the loop.

Comment: I was using setTimeout to change the rate of colour change.

Comment: @coderodour wrong. placing in the loop would lead to some unexpected behaviour...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the result of calling the `Colours` function to setTimeout. You should pass a reference to the function, and pass the arguments with the 3rd argument of setTimeout.

```
window.setTimeout(Colours, 10, count + 1);
```

```js
function Colours(count) {
  if (count > 16777215) {
    count = 0;
  }
  hex = count.toString(16);
  while (hex.length < 6) {
    hex = "0" + hex;
  }
  hex = "#" + hex;
  document.body.style.background = hex;
  window.setTimeout(Colours, 10, count + 1);
}

Colours(0)
```

Comment: Ok thanks have made these changes but this hasn't fixed the issue of it only changing colour at the end

Comment: @Jonasw I think they do the same thing

Comment: @KangarooChief click "Run code snippet" that is fading from dark blue to blue then looping. What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: OK sorry it wasn't displaying correctly in my HTML document. Fixed now.

Comment: You should also avoid Capitalizing your functions as that is the convention for declaring an object. If someone else is reading your code they may get confused.

Comment: Sorry, habit from C#

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't do what you think it does:

```
window.setTimeout(Colours(count),10)
```

This is executing `Colours(count)` *immediately* and setting the timeout for the return value of that function.  Since there's no timeout between executions of the function, the whole thing is blocking and the DOM won't be updated until that blocking code completes.

You want to pass a function itself, not an execution of a function.  In this case it might be something like:

```
window.setTimeout(function () { Colours(count); }, 10)
```

This wraps the call in a function that isn't immediately being executed.  *That* function will then be executed in the timeout.

Comment: @Jonasw: I actually wasn't aware of that functionality until reading the other answer posted here.  It certainly does seem simpler :)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript can be temperamental at times. Your issue is mainly based on the fact that your code does not have the correct delay, and so the browser optimises by only showing the last iteration. The code below will fix this issue, using setTimeout. See the JSFiddle link below.

```
function Colours(count) {
  if (count > 16777215) {
    count = 0;
    }
  hex = count.toString(16);
  while (hex.length < 6) {
    hex = "0" + hex;
  }
  hex = "#" + hex;
  document.body.style.background = hex;
  window.setTimeout(Colours, 10, count + 1);
}

Colours(0)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y68sfptp/1/

Edit: Sorry, just saw the previous answers.